# Need to choose a container to store my data

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I have a data and I need to perform searching and sorting on it. The data are just bunch of struct objects which looks something like this:

```
struct ContactInfo {
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    std::string phoneNumber;
    std::string email;

    ContactInfo(std::string name, std::string phone, std::string email, std::string desc);
    ContactInfo();
};
```

If I keep it in a map with "name" as key, I will have to perform linear search if I search through "description", "phoneNumber" or "email".

My question is: Do I have any better way to keep the data to have faster search?

Comment: _'I will have to perform linear search ...'_ You can add additional indexing maps, using shared pointers to the original `ContactInfo` instances, and various search keys you need.

Comment: You might use boost multi-index: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: @DieterLücking This is for a class, I have to use nothing other than `stl`. I guess   πάντα ῥεῖ's solution is my only choice

Comment: Can you sort cars based on color and size?  not really if you sort by color then your size is out of order, if you sort by size, then your colors get mixed up.  So your left with the obvious choice :  See comment 1.

Comment: You should use more space to accelerate your searching speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associative STL containers (`map` and `unordered_map`) are built around the most typical case of a single index.

If you wish to index on multiple fields, you have several solutions:

1. Simplest: use multiple containers, each indexed on its own field and keeping a copy of the record (update of records become a pain)
2. Bit harder: use multiple containers, each indexed on its own field and *sharing* records (`std::shared_ptr<ContactInfo>`)
3. Harder: same as the previous, but using a "master" container that owns the records for more efficiency (and less indirection)

In your case, I would start with (1) and move to (2) if you have to update the records.

Keep in mind, though, that update is a complicated task because each time you update a record it must be re-indexed on the updated fields. To simplify the look-up you can keep an iterator in each container referencing the item and use those to erase without paying a look-up: this iterator is returned by the call to `insert` when you put your item in `map` (or `unordered_map`).

Comment: I actually used option 2, though with simple pointers. I will move to shared_ptrs. Thanks for help.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: read the comments on the question, only the Standard library is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to do queries where you specify query values for multiple fields, then this is a painful problem to get optimal O(1) running time per query if the total number of fields is large. However it sounds like you only want to query based on one field value at a time. For this, just use a Hashmap or whatever you are using to index quickly by Name, and do the same thing for all the other fields. Since you need O(#records*#fields) storage to store your original data, and each Hashmap or sorted array or whatever you're using has size O(#records) and you have #fields of them if you do it for every field, the total amount of storage is asymptotically no larger than your original data storage size (of course, you'll need to store pointers to records in your search structures instead of the records themselves in order to get this storage bound).